# error: expected initializer before '<' token

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to have [MAGMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/) as backend for [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) in the same way it does already support MKL. While doing so I bump into the error above. The relevant snippets below:

```
template <>
/*ERROR IN THIS LINE >>>>>*/ inline void assign_scalar_eig2magma<magmaDoubleComplex,dcomplex>(magmaDoubleComplex& magmaScalar, const dcomplex& eigenScalar) {
  magmaScalar.x=eigenScalar.real();
  magmaScalar.y=eigenScalar.imag();
}
```

and the `magmaDoubleComplex` is defined in `magma_types.h`:

```
// ========================================
// define types specific to implementation (CUDA, OpenCL, MIC)
// define macros to deal with complex numbers
#if HAVE_CUBLAS
    #include <cublas.h>

    typedef cudaStream_t   magma_queue_t;
    typedef cudaEvent_t    magma_event_t;
    typedef int            magma_device_t;

    typedef cuDoubleComplex magmaDoubleComplex;
    typedef cuFloatComplex  magmaFloatComplex;
```

As far as I can see `magmaDoubleComplex` is declared but this doesn't seem to be the issue here ...

UPDATE: Indeed my mistake, here the template definition is "mkl" and it should be "magma".

```
template<typename MAGMAType, typename EigenType>
static inline void assign_scalar_eig2mkl(MAGMAType& magmaScalar, const EigenType& eigenScalar) {
  magmaScalar=eigenScalar;
}
```

Comment: Is there a declaration of the primary template `assign_scalar_eig2magma` in scope?

Comment: It looks like it's complaining about `assign_scalar_eig2magma` (i.e. the thing "before `<` token"). You need to declare the template itself before you can declare explicit specialisations of it.

Comment: @Mike post your comment as answer and I will accept.